# Añadir datos de FILE a un objeto en java

Tags: java

tengo un programa en el que estoy manejando estructura de datos... Me piden añadir datos sacados del File, a un objeto. No se como realizarlo, muchas gracias y perdón por las molestias, pongo el código:

Donde CPersona es el objeto y lo creo con new, pero no se como añadirle los datos. Muchas gracias y un saludo

```
try( 
            BufferedReader brList = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(lContactos));){
            cadena = brList.readLine();
            System.out.println("Leyendo el archivo "+lContactos.getName());
            cadenaSeparada = cadena.split(";");
            nombre = cadenaSeparada[0];
            direccion = cadenaSeparada[1];
            telefono = cadenaSeparada[2];
            fechaN = cadenaSeparada[3];
            tipoContacto = cadenaSeparada [4];
            
            
            CPersona Persona = new CPersona(nombre, direccion, telefono, fechaNacimiento, tipoContacto);   
            CAgendaContactos unaAgenda = new CAgendaContactos();
```

Comment: El problema es que no puedes extraer los datos? podrías agregar como es tu archivo

Comment: CPersona no es un objeto, es una clase. Supongo que la clase para agenda ha de tener un método para agregar personas.

Answer (score 0):

en primer lugar sino sabes por donde empezar dile a tu profe
que te vuelva a enseñar, ya que para este problema hay varias formas de solucionarlo.

En Java hay varios tipos de ficheros para cuando la información que deseas guardar son objetos propios:
-Ficheros de objetos serializable
-Ficheros de acceso aleatorio
-Ficheros JSON/texto plano
-Ficheros XML
El 2, 3 y 4, son un poco complejos y necesitaría una publicación única para cada uno de ellos, por lo que te explicaré la primera. Con un ejemplo.
En primer lugar nuestra clase tiene que implementar Serializable:

```
public class Alumno implements Serializable{ //Hay que implementar esto para convertirlo en un flujo de 8 bits
```

En segundo lugar nos crearemos una clase, para implementar los métodos que nos permitan acceder a este fichero (guardarAlumnos(), obtenerAlumnos(), etc..)
En esta clase implementaremos los siguientes métodos

```
public void guardarFicheroSerializable(File myFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null; 
    try{    
        //Escribir en el fichero
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos); 
        oos.writeObject(Recursos.alumnos);           
           
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }    
    catch(IOException ex){
        throw new IOException();
    }       
    finally{
        try {
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IOException();
        }             
    }
}
```

con este método escribimos un ArrayList entero en un fichero.

```
 public void abrirFicheroSerializable(File myFile) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null; 
    try{    
        //Escribir en el fichero
        fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis); 
        ArrayList<Alumno> aux = (ArrayList<Alumno>) ois.readObject();   
        for(Alumno auxAlumno: aux){
            if(comprobarNumMatricula(auxAlumno.getNumMatricula()) == false){
                Recursos.alumnos.add(auxAlumno);
            }
        }      
    }catch(IOException ex){
        throw new IOException();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new ClassNotFoundException();
    }       
    finally{
        try {
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IOException();
        }             
    }
}
```

con este método leemos un ArrayList entero.

Espero que te sea de ayuda, de todas formas te dejo un enlace a mi
github de un proyecto en el cual implemento todas esas formas!

[Repositorio a Github Acceso a Ficheros Planos Java](https://github.com/daniiguti/AccesoFicherosJava/blob/main/src/Controlador/CtrlAlumnos.java)